# Changing fonts (and related settings) in wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts

I am using wordpress for my blog/site. I am using Freshnews theme from woothemes as the theme for the blog.

Here is the link:
http://demo.woothemes.com/freshnews/

The font is not that good and it is way too small and the spacing is bad (too congested).

How do I change the fonts, size, spacing (line and paragraph) throughout the blog.

I know I would have to change it somewhere in the stylesheet. But where exactly and how?

And what are the ways to get this done?

Should I install a font somewhere?

Should I use webfonts (like google webfonts)? 
What is the advantage in using this?

or what are the other ways?

Comment: **Where?**: In the stylesheet(s). **How?**: With a text editor. Everything you want to change is right there, *how exactly to do it* is what web designers make a living from, and it's *up to you*. **Should I use webfonts?**: Once again, completely up to you. I admit I do not use WP so there may be theme settings you can adjust, but this is the typical solution - edit the CSS.

Comment: Madmartigan's right, you have to modify style.css in the Wordpress theme directory. [The Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/) should have information on where the files are located and some pointers about how to figure out what to change.

Answer (score 0):

Freshnews is one of woothemes older templates but should come with a custom.css file in your root folder. This file is used to override styles in your themes style sheet. You will want to use chrome developer tools or firebug to determine which fonts you want to adjust.

I assume you wan to change your p tags, to adjust the font family, size, and line-height to so in custom.css put the following. Note that there are many styles to edit to get all the font sizes adjusted. Your best bet is to use chrome developer tool or firebug to find the class and ID's of the styles you want to edit.

```
.entry p {
font-size: 1.2em;
}
p {
font-size: 1.2em;
}
```